# how to add expiration date in datagrid view

Tags: vb.net

I have this code:

```
Dim readers As MySqlDataReader
Dim command As New MySqlCommand
Try
    con.Open()
    Dim query As String
    query = "Select product_code,drug_name,quantity,expiration_date from medicine where expiration_date<=@exp"
    command = New MySqlCommand(query, con)
    command.Parameters.Add("@exp", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now
    readers = command.ExecuteReader
    Dim count As Integer
    count = 0
    While readers.Read
        count = count + 1
    End While
    con.Close()
    If count = 0 Then
        MsgBox("no expiration")
    Else
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(readers)
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: This is not how the reader works. You have depleted the information in the reader with the while loop as it is a forward only collection. Read up on using a mySqlDataAdapter to fill a datatable and then set that datatable as the datasource. for the datagridview. You can also check to see if the datatable is empty to display your no expiration message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using con As New MySqlConnection("your connection string")
        Using command As New MySqlCommand("Select product_code,drug_name,quantity,expiration_date from medicine where expiration_date<=@exp", con)
            command.Parameters.Add("@exp", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now
            con.Open()
            dt.Load(command.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using
    If dt.Rows.Count < 1 Then
        MsgBox("no expiration")
    Else
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    End If
End Sub
```

This should work if your goal is to display the return from the query. The `Using...End Using` blocks ensure that your database objects are closed and disposed even if there is an error.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem please accept as answer by clicking the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer.

Comment: can i ask you something how can i change background color if already expired??

Comment: I searched Google for "conditional background color in DataGridView" and got a slew of answers.